# Shared VPC - Only share a specific subnet to a project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc, google-cloud-networking

Is there a way to share a specific subnet of a `Shared VPC` to a project?

Right now, when I share the subnets of a `Shared VPC`, I can only specify which subnets to share and which projects to share with and then all the shared subnets show up in each project.

I would like to share `shared-subnet-1` to `project-1` and `shared-subnet-2` to `project-2` but I don't want `shared-subnet-1` to show up in `project-2` and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Shared VPC makes use of  Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles for delegated administration access. With Project-level permissions and subnet-level permission, a shared VPC admin can grant permission to use the whole host project or just some/specific subnets, [for details check this GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc#svc_proj_admins). Based on this, using a more granular IAM roles it is possible to grant access to specific resource(s) only.

Directions detail on how to modify the configuration of an existing host project, can be found in this article ([step#7 VPC network sharing mode section](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#create-shared)). In addition to that the same GCP article also describes how to define an IAM role for:

[Service Project Admins for all subnets](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#networkuseratproject)

[Service Project Admins for some subnets](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#networkuseratsubnet)

[Service Accounts as Service Project Admins](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#sa-as-spa)